# disabe OPcache for specific website

Tags: centos6

**Problem:** Running OPCache on web server with production site and Development site causes problems when editing the development site, because PHP pages are cached.

**Question:** Is it possible to turn OPCache off ONLY for the development site, but leave it on for the production website? My dev site is on the same OS, so obviously they are using the same PHP-FPM service.

Answer (score 0):

Since your site is small, there's no real need to have OPcache not rechecking files on each request. Set `opcache.validate_timestamps` to `true` and `opcache.revalidate_freq` to `0`, to have OPcache check whether the file is modified on every request.

When you actually have enough traffic for it to matter, you can run each site on a separate php-fpm pool, each with different settings. Though, it's been my experience that this performance tweak (disabling `validate_timestamps`) saves so little time in comparison to everything else PHP is doing that it's not very useful at all.